# userUsageReport() not returning information for a user

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client, google-admin-audit-api

I've been trying to use Admin SDK Reports API through `google-api-python-client` to audit the Drive usage of my G Suite users. I need to know how many quota they have used on a week. The problem is that when I try to search for an specific user that exists:

```py
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
#I replaced the real values with example ones.
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(filename="somefile.p12", service_account_email="someservice@mail.iam.gserviceaccount.com", scopes=SCOPES)
delegated_creds=creds.create_delegated('gsuiteowner@mail.com')
service = build('admin', 'reports_v1', credentials=delegated_creds)
results = service.userUsageReport().get(userKey="some@usermail.com",date="2020-08-27").execute()
```

I'm just getting 2 types of answers: the first one, a PARTIAL_DATA_AVAILABLE error when I try to search data from the last 7 days, and an empty result (just a dict with `kind` and `etag` keys) when I try to search data from more than 7 days. The strange thing is that when I search information for my own mail (the G Suite owner), it returns me the properly data I expect, I've already tried searching for several mails that are not the owner and I know they exist. I'm using a delegated account in Python.

Comment: Whom is your account delegating? Yourself or `someuser@mail.com`? Please provide the whole code snippet if possible.

Comment: The account I'm delegating is the owner of the G Suite. And okay, I updated the question showing the full code snippet.

Comment: Your code looks correct. It is normal that you get `PARTIAL_DATA_AVAILABLE` when accessing recent data, but receiving an empty result is less expected. What happens if you define `userKey="all"`?

Comment: When I search using `userKey="all"`, I get the dict with the correct information. The problem is I don't need the global information, but the specific one of every user.

Comment: In this case the same request should work for any of the users for which you can retrieve the data correctly when specifying "all". I assume you are querying users belonging to your domain? What do you mean by "not owners"?

Comment: Hmm, that's true, nobody of the users I am searching belong to my domain. Everyone has a different domain. How would I check for users that belong to other domains? The strange thing is that when I use `activities()` instead of `userUsageReport()` I can see the activities by other users that don't belong to my domain.

Comment: `userUsageReport()` refers to the users of your domain - it wouldn't be good practice if you were able to retrieve any user's activity - that would mean vice versa that any user in the world could retrieve your activity...

Comment: Yeah, but my account is the super administrator of the G Suite, I'm doing this code to get how many quota are some users using, but from different domains. So if I have those permissions, isn't there any way to get that info?

Comment: Do you mean different Subdomains or completely different domains? You need to be an admin for each domain you want to get data for.

Comment: I don't know if I explained myself well, I mean, I have a G Suite account where there are 8 teamdrives in the same domain, each user has access to the teamdrives. I am administrator of every teamdrive and superadmin from the domain itself.

Comment: What do you mean then by "but from different domains"?

Comment: I meant to say teamdrives.

Comment: So shall I disregard the comment "nobody of the users I am searching belong to my domain. Everyone has a different domain"? Do you query for `userUsageReport()` as stated above or do you specify `parameters` or `filters`?And what is your request for `activities()`? Which information exactly are you trying to retrieve for a given user?  The files he creates/modifies? Or also the files he only views?